# Limit the depth of properties documented by Swashbuckle for [ProducesResponseType] annotations

Tags: .net, swashbuckle

In .NET I can automatically generate documentation using my XML markup and tags on my methods. e.g.

```
    // DELETE: api/MyType
    /// <summary>
    /// Deletes a MyType with specified ID
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key">The ID of the MyType to delete</param>
    /// <returns>The data for the deleted MyType</returns>
    [HttpDelete]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(MyType), 200)]
```

This works well, except in the case where I have an object with very deep nesting. When swashbuckle generates the documentation from [ProducesResponseType] it recurses every property right down the tree which can be enormous. I only want the top level of properties for the object itself.

Is it possible to do this?

The generated object response documentation looks like this

```
  "IsAvlOverride": true,
  "Notes": "string",
  "DateRejected": "2018-02-26T21:53:26.127Z",
  "GeometryType": 0,
  "PrimaryTagId": 0,
  "OptimisticLockField": 0,
  "Atplot": [
    {
      "UniqueId": "string",
      "Hrid": "string",
      "CreatedBy": 0,
      "CreatedOn": "2018-02-26T21:53:26.127Z",
      "ModifiedBy": 0,
      "ModifiedOn": "2018-02-26T21:53:26.127Z",
      "AtpLotId": 0,
      "AtpId": 0,
      "LotId": 0,
      "ItemInspect": "string",
      "DateInspect": "2018-02-26T21:53:26.127Z",
      "TimeInspect": "2018-02-26T21:53:26.127Z",
      "DateApproved": "2018-02-26T21:53:26.127Z",
      "ApprovedById": 0,
      "ApprovalComments": "string",
      "OptimisticLockField": 0,
      "Approval": [
        {
          "UniqueId": "string",
          "Hrid": "string",
          "CreatedBy": 0,
          "CreatedOn": "2018-02-26T21:53:26.127Z",
          "ModifiedBy": 0,
          "ModifiedOn": "2018-02-26T21:53:26.127Z",
          "ApprovalId": 0,
          "ApprovalItemTypeId": 0,
          "ApprovalSubtypeId": 0,
          "RequestToId": 0,
          "RequestById": 0,
          "RequestText": "string",
          "RequestDate": "2018-02-26T21:53:26.127Z",
          "RequiredDate": "2018-02-26T21:53:26.127Z",
          "EmailDate": "2018-02-26T21:53:26.127Z",
          "ResponseDate": "2018-02-26T21:53:26.127Z",
          "ResponseText": "string",
          "ApprovalStatusTypeId": 0,
          "ProjectId": 0,
          "CloseOutDate": "2018-02-26T21:53:26.127Z",
          etc...
```

I want it to look like;

```
  "IsAvlOverride": true,
  "Notes": "string",
  "DateRejected": "2018-02-26T21:53:26.127Z",
  "GeometryType": 0,
  "PrimaryTagId": 0,
  "OptimisticLockField": 0,
  "Atplot": [Atplot_object]
```

Comment: I've not seen any option like that on swashbuckle... What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I edited to give an example

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that what you are asking is a good idea... 
Anyone trying to consume your API will not get the full model

But you can use `[JsonIgnore]` on your model to ignore the field/property

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to domaindrivendev at the github issues, the best you can do easily is to reduce the noise as follows. It works for me

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.DefaultModelRendering(ModelRendering.Model);
    c.DefaultModelExpandDepth(1); 
});
```

Comment: It fixes only a model, not an example, right? The example still expands the whole database.